# Install conda packages from internal artifactory in docker

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

i would like to install some conda packages from a interanal artifactory in my docker image. On my vm is no internet but the repo in the artifactory points external to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le/.

With --channel i am tring to force the internal artifactory on the conda install but somehow conda puts "https://conda.anaconda.org/" in front of the channel URL. As you can see in the error under channel URLs. Of course the installation then fails because the URL is wrong. Is there a way tho tell conda not to do that? Didn´t find any solution with internal artifactory, conda and docker.
ps I am a beginner please be gentle :-)

```
RUN bash Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-ppc64le.sh -b -p ${CONDA_DIR} && \
    ${CONDA_DIR}/bin/conda init && \
    ${CONDA_DIR}/bin/**conda install -y --channel** user:password@artifactoryurl/artifactory/conda-remote/linux-ppc64le/repodata.json \
        numpy=1.19.1 \
        scipy=1.5.0 \
        pyyaml=5.3.1 \
        future=0.18.2 \
        h5py=2.10.0 \
        psycopg2=2.8.5 \
        lxml=4.5.2 \
        pandas=1.0.5 \
        alembic=1.4.2 \
        scikit-learn=0.23.1 \
        cudatoolkit=9.0 \
        cudnn=7.1.4
```

Error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 265, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 415, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1011, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 228, in get_reduced_index
        repodata_fn=repodata_fn)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 105, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 97, in <lambda>
        subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 63, in __call__
        assert not channel.package_filename
    AssertionError

`$ /root/miniconda3/bin/conda install -y --channel user:password@artifactoryurl/artifactory/conda-remote/linux-ppc64le/repodata.json numpy=1.19.1 scipy=1.5.0 pyyaml=5.3.1 future=0.18.2 h5py=2.10.0 psycopg2=2.8.5 lxml=4.5.2 pandas=1.0.5 alembic=1.4.2 scikit-learn=0.23.1 cudatoolkit=9.0 cudnn=7.1.4`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_DIR=/root/miniconda3
               CONDA_ROOT=/root/miniconda3
                     PATH=/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/.bin/:/opt/app-root/src/.npm-
                          global/bin/:/opt/app-root/src/bin:/opt/app-
                          root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
         STI_SCRIPTS_PATH=/usr/libexec/s2i

     active environment : None
       user config file : /opt/app-root/src/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __glibc=2.28
       base environment : /root/miniconda3  (writable)
           **channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/user:password@artifactoryurl/artifactory/conda-remote/linux-ppc64le/repodata.json**
                          
https://conda.anaconda.org/user:password@artifactoryurl/artifactory/conda-remote/repodata.json/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-ppc64le
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /root/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /opt/app-root/src/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /root/miniconda3/envs
                          /opt/app-root/src/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-ppc64le
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.23.0 CPython/3.7.7 Linux/4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.ppc64le rhel/8.2 glibc/2.28
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```